# Python TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable ​

Tags: python, object, floating-point, typeerror, iterable

I've been making a model in Python, but I cannot understand where's my mistake.

My IDE says that the problem is with 'rule1' , but I am not sure why. I've read about this typeerror and I found that the function 'range()' helps, but that generated me more problems. After that, I found that use '//' instead of '/' would help, but nothing changed.
I am not sure if I am not using these solutions right or my problem has more that one mistake in the code.
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
def model3(T,mu,alpha,beta):
    d_3=np.zeros((3,3))
        
    
    for h in range (T):
        rew1=1
        rew2=1
        q1=0.5
        q2=0.5
        delta1=rew1-q1
        delta2=rew2-q2
        q1=q1+alpha*delta1
        q2=q2+alpha*delta2
        Q=range(q1+q2)
        rule1=math.exp(beta*q1)//sum(math.exp(beta*(q1+q2)))
        rule2=math.exp(beta*q2)//sum(math.exp(beta*(q1+q2)))
        p=[rule1,rule2] 
    #Make choice according to choice probailities
        c=random.choice(p)
    #Generated reward
        r_3=np.random.rand()
        d_3[0,1]=1
        d_3[0,2]=0
    
        if c==p[0]:       
            m_3=mu[0]     
            d_3[1,0]=k[0] 
        else:
            m_3=mu[1]     
            d_3[2,0]=k[1]  

    
    
        if r_3<m_3:
            reward_3=1    
            if m_3==mu[0]:          
                d_3[1,1]=d_3[1,1]+1
            else:
                d_3[2,1]=d_3[2,1]+1 
    
        else:
            reward_3=0
            if m_3==mu[0]:          
                d_3[1,2]=d_3[1,2]+1 
            else:
                d_3[2,2]=d_3[2,2]+1 
     
                    
    return(d_3)
```

Comment: Could you please show your entire traceback info?

Comment: `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-a45e5a9dac98> in <module>
----> 1 model3(T,mu,.4,10)

<ipython-input-11-d63b00e9209e> in model3(T, mu, alpha, beta)
     12         q1=q1+alpha*delta1
     13         q2=q2+alpha*delta2
---> 14      Q=range(q1+q2)
     15         rule1=math.exp(beta*q1)//sum(math.exp(beta*(q1+q2)))
     16         rule2=math.exp(beta*q2)//sum(math.exp(beta*(q1+q2)))

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in this line:

```
Q=range(q1+q2)
```

Both q1 and q2 are floats and even though they add up to 1.0 - it is still a float and you can't use `range()` with floating point arguments.

EDIT:
As per the comment below, you can try doing:

```
Q = range(int(q1 + q2))
```

Comment: Yeah I think so too. Using `int` conversion should solve the problem.

Comment: I added that change to 'Q' and now I used it in 'rule1' and 'rule2' instead of 'q1+q2'. But this new TypeError appear:  'unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'range'' I tried to wrote a 'range(int(' for each q but did't work

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains 2 range() function

```
for h in range(T):
```

and

```
Q = range(q1 + q2)
```

The range function can't iterate over floating point numbers so try using this  below code lines to solve your issue.

```
for h in range(int(T)):
```

and

```
Q = range(int(q1 + q2))
```